# Java can't get client or server response

Tags: java, connection, connection-string, server

I'm from Poland, so I'm sorry for any mistakes.
I've coding for a while a small server and client connection, when I stopped on annoying problem. When I send from client to server information (String), server can get it, but can't respone to it.

Here it is code.

**Client**

```
private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
       String host = "localhost";
       int port = 25002;
       InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
       socket = new Socket();
       socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 5000);

       //Send the message to the server
       System.out.println("< "+sendMessage(socket));
       //socket.shutdownOutput();
       System.out.println("> "+getMessage(socket));
   }catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
   }catch (IOException e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
   }catch (IllegalBlockingModeException e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
   }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
   }finally{
      //Closing the socket
      try{
         socket.close();
      }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
      }
   }
}

public static String sendMessage(Socket client){
    try {
        String message = "test";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        writer.print(message);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        return message;
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
        return "false";
     }
}

public static String getMessage(Socket client){
            try {
                BufferedReader socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                return socketReader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
                return "false";
            }
        }
```

**And.. server**

```
public class kRcon{
        private static Socket socket;
        private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private static Thread u;

        private static class Server extends Thread {
                public void run() {
                        int port = 25002;
                        try {
                            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        while(true) {
                          try {
                             socket = serverSocket.accept();
                             BufferedReader socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                             BufferedWriter socketWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                             String str = socketReader.readLine();
                        socketReader.close();
                             System.out.println(str);
                             socketWriter.write("test");
                             socketWriter.flush();
                             socketWriter.close();
                          }
                        }catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
               }
         public static void init(){
         try {
            u = new Server();
            u.setName("Server");
            u.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // changed
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**
If, I start server first all looks nice.
So, I start the client with parametr "test", nad output to console is:

```
< test
Socket is closed // changed
```

On server-side in console I have:

```
"test"
Socket is closed // changed
```

I tried to shutdown inputs and outputs and dosen't work.. I don't know to do now. Please help :c

**Edited 2015-04-03**
I've changed lines with comment "changed".

**For Google, and readers**
To fix problem, don't close StreamReaders nad StreamWriters on client's sides.
Thanks to [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp), for help!
*Greetings from Poland.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an exception, print it. Don't just throw away all that information. And don't return magic `Strings` either. In this case you should have let the exception propagate. If you had done all that you would have seen the exception `SocketException: socket closed` being thrown by `getMessage(),` and you would have had something concrete to investigate, instead of a complete mystery.

It is caused by closing the `PrintWriter` in `sendMessage().` Closing either the input or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.